# How to specify a validation domain for AWS CDK when using tokens for domain names

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm requesting a domain certificate from an AWS CDK stack.
For the domain name, I use a value from AWS Parameter Store like:

```
const domainName = StringParameter.valueForStringParameter(this, `/musical/${branch}/PaymentDomain`)

const cert = new Certificate(this, 'Certificate', {
  domainName: domainName,
})
```

When I try to run *cdk synth* or *cdk deploy* I get an error *When using Tokens for domain names, 'validationDomains' needs to be supplied*

I tried to add *validationDomains* to the certificate request but not only is this property depreciated I also don't know how to specify the validation domain. It has a typescript format that I don't understand:

```
CertificateProps.validationDomains?: {
  [domainName: string]: string;
}
```

Since *validationDomains* is depreciated, the docs say I should use *validation* but when I try to use *validation* the docs say that should be used for the validation method (DNS or email)

How do I create a correct certificate request when I use a token for a domain name?

Answer (score 5):

AWS won't create certificates unless it can validate you own the domain for which you want the certificate.  It has two ways it can validate you own the domain.  Through DNS or through email.

If using email validation to create a certificate for my.domain.com an email will be sent to admin,  administrator, hostmaster, postmaster, and webmaster all @my.domain.com or you can also specify a super domain so it will send to domain.com instead.

If using DNS validation, AWS will generate a specific record to add as a sub domain of my.domain.com to prove you own it.  If using Route53 HostedZone for this domain, you can specify the zone and it is all seamless.  If not, you can still do DNS validation but you have to manually (or write a custom resource) create the record that AWS needs or the stack will never finish updating.

```
const domainName = StringParameter.valueForStringParameter(this, `/musical/${branch}/PaymentDomain`)

const cert = new Certificate(this, 'Certificate', {
  domainName: domainName,
  validation: CertificateValidation.fromDns(hostedZone), // Seamless
  validation: CertificateValidation.fromDns(), // You need to create DNS validation record manually
  validation: CertificateValidation.fromEmail() // Click link from email
})
```

Pick one of those validation methods and include it when creating the certificate

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone else finds this useful. But I got the same error when I didn't have a correctly formed domain name. I think I had a null somewhere while forming a string for a particular region. This resulted in an invalid domain name format.

For example, I was using

```
domainName: 'hello.world.'
```

instead of (say)

```
domainName: 'hello.world.com'
```

This took me way longer to debug than I'd like to admit since the error message doesn't tell you exactly what may have happened.